# How to Pass in Certificates and Corresponding Password Files to Docker

Tags: java, linux, docker, certificate, containers

I'm fairly new to Docker and while there is a ton of information out there, I'm not sure I understand enough to decipher the correct solution to what I'm asking here. Basically, I have a java app/jar file that I want to run inside of a docker container. Based on some examples on the internet, I've created a Dockerfile that looks like:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ADD target/custom-app-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar custom-app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Xmx4096", "-Xms1024m", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/pki/java/trustKS.jks","-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$(cat /home/username/scripts/jks-password)", "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/etc/pki/java/server_keystore.p12", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$(cat /home/username/scripts/server-password)", "-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12", "-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2", "-jar", "/custom-app.jar"]
```

In some of the params I pass into the ENTRYPOINT command, I say where my keystore and trust store files are located, as well as the corresponding files that hold their respective passwords/passphrases.

What is the best way in docker to have the user who uses this image to pass in their own certificates with their own passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a container run locally on a single node, especially a developer environment, you typically mount a volume from the host with these credentials. E.g.

```
docker run -v /host/path/creds.pem:/container/path/creds.pem:ro your_image
```

If you can get to swarm mode, docker injects secrets as a read only in memory file that is only stored encrypted on the managers, and in memory on the workers that need the secret. This can be as easy as:

```
docker secret create creds /host/path/creds.pem
```

And then run the container as a service:

```
docker service create --secret creds your_image
```

More details on secrets are available at: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/

For reproducibility, I typically do this in a compose file. You can find the syntax here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Couple of follow-up questions I have are: do I need to modify anything in my current Dockerfile? And since I have a separate file for each of the truststore, keystore, truststore password and keystore password - 4 in total, how do I mount all of them?

Comment: @Pr0pagate this all happens at runtime, so nothing to change in the Dockerfile other than make sure it knows where to find your files. Pass multiple individual files with multiple `-v` flags, or you can mount an entire directory.

Comment: Related to this, if I specify an environment variable in a docker-compose.yml file, is it possible to read in that environment variable as a param to the ENTRYPOINT command in my Dockerfile? I tried this with "-Djavax-net.ssl.keyStorePassword=${KS_PASSWORD}" but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Environment variables work, but you need a shell to expand them. The Json/exec syntax you use for `ENTRYPOINT` explicitly bypasses the shell and runs the command directly. The typical solution is to run a shell script instead, that being a shell expands the variables in the script, and the last command begins with `exec` to replace the shell with your command.